# External hard disk was removed while accessing, chances of recovery?

Tags: data-recovery

I unknowingly removed a 250gb external drive (2.5") while it was being accessed and now it no longer works, tried photorec/testdisk, no luck. Its no longer being recognised as a drive.

Considering data recovery companies to send it to, but they charge about $300 (minimum). I am willing to shell out as some things on there are somewhat important, but is there realistically any chance these companies will be able to recover much?

Comment: what file system? if its NTFS, tried force-mounting it on linux?

Comment: How was it connected? Is it in an enclosure?

Comment: it was NTFS. connected in a caddy/enclosure. I have not yet tried gparted, i guess that is the next logical step.

Comment: Don't know if i have NTFS to thank, or just the solid build of the toshiba drive but 1 day later, it magically returned to life. Still waiting to see whether it now grows fangs and develops a taste for blood.

Comment: well it got worse again after the miraculous recovery. had to resort to the freezer trick, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the freezer trick after experiencing the click of death, worked for long enough to allow me to recover all files, I would recommend the freezer trick any time. 2 hours in the freezer, in a couple of ziplock bags. when you take it back out, make sure the connectors are dry (use a dry towel). it should boot up in Win/Linux/whatever.